# Facebook Catalog no carga imágenes de AWS Cloudfront

Tags: api, aws, facebook, lambda

Tengo un problema cuando intento subir algunas imágenes al catálogo de Facebook Shopping utilizando una fuente de datos que en este caso es esta API.
[image: API URL Facebook Shopping]

Las imágenes son entregadas por Cloudfront CDN, pero facebook no puede descargarlas.

[image: Facebbok Shoppin Error]

Comment: Estas en StackOverflow en Español.

Comment: Hola @René Gracias. ya lo traducí.
Saludos.

Comment: Cuáles librerías intentas usar?

Comment: Hola @GoyoDavidBeaumont en este caso no uso ninguna librería solo retorno un XML con la información que obtengo desde mis bases de datos para que facebook pueda usarlo como un origen de datos, tal cual lo indica la documentación:
https://www.facebook.com/business/help/120325381656392?id=725943027795860
El problema es que mis imagenes se entregan mendiante cloudfront y facebook no puede subirlas a su catalogo.

Comment: En teoria el cloudfront lo que hace es convertir tu archivo original en formato CDN, porque no intentas pasarle la URL original?

Comment: Tambien verifica que cloudfront esta configurado para ser accesible publicamente.

Comment: Gracias @GoyoDavidBeaumont me funcionó cuando tranforme las imagenes a .png las tenía en formato .jpeg